# Alternate row coloring in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, rows

I have a table with expand and  collapse of rows, with column sortable.
Below is my code, is there is any ways to improve its performance.
And read appending complete group of rows into dom improves performance, but if i do out of $.each() loop it throws error.
[teble demo](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a8dd83ed6e.gif)

```
var alt = true;
var altSub = true;

$.each(myData, function(index, row) {

    var noRow = $(row).length;
    var firstRow = $(row[0]);

    for (var i=0; i < noRow; i++) {
        if(firstRow.attr('id') == $(row[i]).attr('id')) {
            if(alt == true) {
                firstRow.removeClass("odd").addClass("even");
                alt = !alt;
                altSub = true;
            } else if( alt == false) {
                firstRow.removeClass("even").addClass("odd");
                alt = !alt;
                altSub = true;
            }
        } else {
            if(altSub == true) {
                $(row[i]).removeClass("alt_row_sub").addClass("alt_row_sub2");
                altSub = !altSub;
            } else if( altSub == false) {
                $(row[i]).removeClass("alt_row_sub2").addClass("alt_row_sub");
                altSub = !altSub;
            }
        }
    }
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

[link text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a8dd83ed6e.gif)

Comment: please, provide a bigger demo of your table

Comment: and why is this a community wiki? It's a perfect good question.

Comment: @Natrium -- I have updated image.

Answer (score 15):

You might find the [`:even`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/even) and [`:odd`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/odd) selectors useful.

You could then use them like this:

```
$('.stripyTable tr:even').addClass('even');
$('.stripyTable tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('.stripyTable .submenu tr:even').addClass('alt_row_sub');
$('.stripyTable .submenu tr:odd').addClass('alt_row_sub2');
```

The other thing to consider is whether you can get the different styling of the subsections just with CSS, then in your JS you only need to worry about applying the odd / even classes. The CSS might look something like:

```
.odd { background-color: blue; }
.even { background-color: white; }
.sub .odd { background-color: green; }
.sub .even { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its not working properly. it looks like this http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/da55af5e55.gif

Comment: I'd assume that you have some hidden rows which are causing the striping to look wrong. But without seeing your source it is hard to see what's causing that. Using the :visible selector <http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/visible> when you are applying the striping might help.

Comment: Here is some code that will hopefully illustrate my point: http://jsbin.com/iwuqe

Comment: Yes, i have expand and collapse rows, one more thing is i cant assign class only to visible rows, if it expands/collapse then again symmetry will not be there.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way that I have found of working around this is to reapply the CSS classes after the rows are shown/hidden.

Answer (score 2):

[Tutorials:Zebra Striping Made Easy](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy) from the jQuery is a great tutorial on how to do the zebra striping.

Comment: this zebra striping will be applicable in my case. If u look that my demo image, it gives an idea. My table has collapse and expand, because of that have color in group.

Comment: I once heard someone calling it "pajama striping" :-)

Comment: I reminded of the quote from Hitchikers' Guide to the Galaxy `Oh, that was easy,' says Man, and for an encore goes on to prove that black is white and gets
himself killed on the next zebra crossing.”`

Answer (score 0):

you are inside each loop, do this :

```
$.each(myData, function(index, row) {

       if(index % 2 == 0)
       {
            row.addClass("AltRow");
       }
)};
```