# How can I zebra stripe a gridview that uses jquery tablesorter?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview, tablesorter, zebra-striping

I have an asp.net GridView that I use the tablesorter on:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("[id$='_myGridView']").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]] });
  });
```

How can I apply zebra striping that re-stripes when re-sorting?

Edit:  As @Chetan Sastry pointed out, it's as simple as:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("[id$='_myGridView']").tablesorter({ sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'] });
  });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979669/alternate-row-coloring-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the zebra widget in tablesorter plugin? This says it is part of plugin core - http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-widgets.html

Comment: Don't forget with a gridview you may need to render the <thead><tbody> etc. for tablesorter to work, as seen in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978990/how-can-i-use-jquery-tablesorter-with-an-asp-net-gridview

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `.tablesorter()` applies classes of `odd` and `even` on the rows of your table. The CSS rule from the Tablesorter webpage is:

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td { background-color: #F0F0F6 }
```