# Set color of alternate row using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I am trying to use query to set color of alternate rows of a html table. But every time I add a new row query switches the color of the whole table. Here is the Javascript code I am using:

```
var alternate = true;
function addRow(data) {
    if(alternate){
        $("table.live_feed").find('tbody.main').prepend(data).css("background", "#f1f1f1");
        alternate = false;
    }else{
        $("table.live_feed").find('tbody.main').prepend(data).css("background", "white");
        alternate = true;
    }
}
```

PS: I looked as some similar questions on Stack Overflow where they change the color of odd or even rows. I do not want to change the color of rows that are already present, I only want to change the color of new rows being added.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternate row coloring in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979669/alternate-row-coloring-in-jquery)

Comment: You might find it easiest to add a class to those newly-added rows `class="new"` (for example), and use a selector such as `$('tr.new:nth-child(odd)')` to target the odd rows of those newly-added rows.

Comment: Why do you only want to consider "new rows"? Surely all rows in the table have the zebra striping? It's just making it more complicated to only consider new rows.

Comment: What is `data`? Does it have any `id` or `class` to it that you could do a `.css('background-color', 'yourColor')` to? Also try using `background-color` if your just changing the color

Comment: You can do this completely with CSS in newer browsers...

Comment: @Felix - how can i do this completely in css ???

Comment: @thirtydot - if I change color of odd/even rows instead of only new rows, then whenever a new row is added  all the rows will switch color because adding a new row will make all odd rows even and all even rows odd.

Comment: @Ansh: I see. There are still more elegant ways of solving this, but there's only any point in implementing a better way if you can also *delete* rows. If you're not deleting, what you have will work fine. If you are deleting, you can kludge around it (again) or implement something better.

Comment: Just take the same selector as posted above: `tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: grey; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.css` is acting on the found item (tbody.main), instead you want it to act on data:

```
var data = $(data).css("background", "#f1f1f1");
$("table.live_feed").find('tbody.main').prepend(data);
```

As a side note, for alternating row colours you can utilise the selectors `:odd` and `:even`

**Example:**

```
$('tr:odd').css('background', 'lightgray');
```

Answer (score 1):

`prepend` and `append` and other DOM insertion methods don't return the just created elements, but the jQuery object where you called them.
In your code, the `css` call is applied to the `tbody.main` jQuery object.

In this example you can see how the returned element of the `append` call is the `div` element with `test` id.

http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/VUrhZ/

In the same example you can see a workaround to apply `css` to the just inserted element using `first()` after `prepend`.